# Is it possible to restrict content in wordpress?

Tags: plugins, theme-development

I just upload my blog with wordpress in my host. But I want to make some posts restricted to only those who are logged in and in some cases, the ones who pay for some "super premium" content. I have no idea if there's a plugin to do that or maybe another way to do it, but I really need it. It could be perfect to sign up by email, or social media and get those emails later to add them to a newsletter. Thank you so much for your help and guidance!

Comment: Take a look here (http://bfy.tw/AVyl)[several options]. Advice for plugins are not allowed, sorry.

Comment: The answer is "yes". not sure what is the actual question here

Comment: @Charles your LMGTFY link doesn't work, so: [Here it is](http://bfy.tw/AWJS) :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look up membership plugins. There are several options. Some free some paid. Other than that, you can definitely use custom templates and WordPress functions to restrict content to certain users.

Comment: I found a plugin named "Simple Membership" it's free and it is what I was looking for! Thanks for the tip.